# how to change the second value of an array in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

**Value input**

"ItemInternalId" : [ "01", **"02"**, "011055000000345" ]

**Value output expected**

"ItemInternalId" : [ "01", **"16"**, "011055000000345" ]

Jolt only has two functions, **`"lastElement"`** and **`"firstElement"`**, so I couldn't find anything on the internet that modified the second value

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a **modify** transformation which has those functions, but a **shift** transformation spec along with index of the respective component such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { //stands for "ItemInternalId"
        "1": { // the level of the second component of the array in which index starts from zero
          "#16": "&2" // the fixed value might be assigned by prepending the value with "#" on the left-hand-side, &2 represents going the tree two levels up to grab the tag of the array
        },
        "*": "&1"//else case. The &1 on the right-hand-side represents going the tree one level up to grab the tag of the array
      }
    }
  }
]
```

assuming your input is

```json
{
  "ItemInternalId": [
    "01",
    "02",
    "011055000000345"
  ]
}
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]